# Cost function of Convolutional Neural Networ not serving intended purpose

Tags: math, machine-learning, neural-network

So I have built a CNN and now I am trying to get the training of my network to work effectively despite my lack of a formal education on the topic. I have decided to use stochastic gradient descent with a standard mean squared error cost function. As stated in the title, the problem seems to lie within the cost function.
When I use a couple of training examples, I calculate the mean squared error for each, and get the mean, and use that as the full error. There are two output neurons, one for face, and one for not a face; which ever is higher is the class that is yielded. Essentially, if a training example yields the wrong classification, I calculate the error (with the desired value being the value of the class that was yielded).

Example:

Input an image of a face--->>>
Face: 500
Not face: 1000

So in this case, the network says that the image isn't a face, when in fact it is. The error comes out to:
500 - 1000 = -500
-500^2 = 250000 <<--error
(correct me if i'm doing anything wrong)

As you can see the desired value is set to the value of the incorrect class that was selected.

Now this is all good (from what I can tell), but here is my issue:

As I perform b-prop on the network multiple times, the mean cost of the entire training set falls to 0, but this is only because all of the weights in the network are becoming 0, so all classes always become 0.

After training:

Input not face->
Face: 0
Not face: 0

--note that if the classes are the same, the first one is selected

(0-0)^0 = 0 <<--error

So the error is being minimized to 0 (which is good I guess), but obviously not the way we want.

So my question is this:
How do I minimize the space between the classes when the class is wrong, but also get it to overshoot the incorrect class so that the correct class is yielded.

//example
Had this: (for input of face)
Face: 100
Not face: 200

Got this:
Face: 0
Notface: 0

Want this: (or something similar)
Face: 300
Not face: 100

I hope this question wasn't too vague...
But any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The way you're computing the error doesn't correspond to the standard 'mean squared error'. But, even if you were to fix it, it makes more sense to use a different type of outputs and error that are specifically designed for classification problems.

One option is to use a single output unit with a [sigmoid](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#sigmoid_neurons) activation function. This neuron would output the probability that the input image is a face. The probability that it's not a face is given by 1 minus this value. This approach will work for binary classification problems. [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) outputs are another option. You'd have two output units: the first outputs the probability that the input image is a face, and the second outputs the probability that it's not a face. This approach will also work for multi-class problems, with one output unit for each class.

In either case, use the [cross entropy loss](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html) (also called log loss). Here, you have a target value (face or no face), which is the true class of the input image. The error is the negative log probability that the network assigns to the target.

Most neural nets that perform classification work this way. You can find many good tutorials [here](http://deeplearning.net/), and read [this online book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/).